# Or condition not working in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have to  write a regex condition in which A token only contains letters (i.e. `a-z` or `A-Z`), `"-"` (hyphen), or `"(underscore) "` . Moreover, a token cannot starts or ends with `"-"` or `"_"` .
I tried but i am not able to get that

```
text = "this is a breath-taking ambitious movie; test text: abc_dcd abc_ dvr89w, abc-dcd -abc"

tokens=re.findall(r'[\-\_][a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+-+_[a-zA-Z]', text)
```

Comment: yes, and what _did_ you write?

Comment: tokens=re.findall(r'[^\-\_][a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+-+_[a-zA-Z]', newtext)

Comment: which is the second forbidden char?

Comment: its an underscore "_"

Comment: your starting char range needs a negation: `[\-\_]` => `[^\-_]`

Answer (score 3):

I assumed in your `newtext` it was literally just a string of space separated tokens, so here's a bunch of negative lookbehind/ahead assertions:

```
import re
s = 'foo _foo_ _foo foo_ 123 _123 _123_ 123_ -foo- -foo foo- 5fOo-bAr3 12-3' 
tokens = re.findall(r'\b(?![-_])(?<![-_])[\w\-]+?(?![-_])(?<![-_])\b', s)
print(tokens)
# ouptut 
# ['foo', '123', '5fOo-bAr3', '12-3']
```

To explain what's going on, there's basically 4 parts:

1. `\b(?![-_])` means don't match if after a word boundary character i.e. `\b`there is a dash or underscore. In this case, think of a word boundary as the edge of a contiguous block of word characters; word character being a-z, A-Z, or underscore (`_`). Which in this case could be a space or even a dash.
2. `(?<![-_])[\w\-]+?` means don't match if to the right of a contiguous block of word characters and dashes (in other words, our definition of a token) is a dash or underscore. Yeah you need both the lookahead assertion and lookbehind assertion next to each other otherwise the `[\w\-]+?` will consume a leading dash.
3. `[\w\-]+?(?![-_])` means don't match if after our definition of a token is a dash or underscore
4. `(?<![-_])\b` means don't match if to the left of the left edge of the token is a dash or underscore

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful if you give a starting example and desired output.
From what I understand this might be something that can get you started:

```
import re
example = ['[Beta-blockers-]', 'Magic!', '19_80', 'Presse medicale']
output = [''.join(re.findall(r'[^\]\[.!][A-z0-9]+[^\]\[.!-]', i)) for i in example]
```

Output:

```
['Beta-blockers', 'Magic', '19_80', 'Presse medicale']
```

Comment: you can remove `k for k in ` as there's no test on `k`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look like this instead:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\-\_]*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]
```

This uses the `|` (or) operator to make sure it matches one of two things. The first is `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\-\_]*[a-zA-Z]`. This makes sure it starts with an allowed starting character (`[a-zA-Z]`). Then it allows any number of allowed characters (`[a-zA-Z\-\_]*`) and then makes sure it ends with an allowed ending character (`[a-zA-Z]`).

The part after the `|` is to make sure it matches single-character tokens.

Comment: This is almost correct but it doesnt display the underscore '_' in the abc token instead of not printing that at all